# Can I attach vscode to manually run gdb session?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I have a large c++ project which I'd like to debug within vscode.

The issue is this application isn't run directly from the executable, rather by calling a ksh script which sets up a lot of environment variables before calling the executable itself.

There is a "-debugger" flag settable when calling this script which will launch gdb in the terminal you ran it from and allow you to debug the application that way.

I'd like to be able to use the visual debugging inside vscode (step, continue, explore data structures etc). My question is can I get vscode to connect to this running gdb session? Can I get vscode to run my script and wait for gdb to initalise and do it that way?

I have tried the following in my `launch.json` file.

```
{
   "name": "Attach Debugger",
   "type": "cppdbg",
   "request": "attach",
   "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
   "MIMode": "gdb",
   "program": "${workspaceRoot}/path/to/my/executable",
   "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I can start the gdb session via my script, then call this launch task and select that process. However it does not attach properly. I cannot set any breakpoints inside vscode, I cannot step etc. I must be missing something.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you think about writing the launch json file to emulate the start script? Setting some environment variables does not sound difficult and everyone in the team will appreciate it when they get the json file from you and don't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: "setting some environment variables" is a huge understatement for what this script does. It is huge and impossible to replicate this way. Thanks for the suggestion though.